# .append() by index number multiplying with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, append

I am trying to have values appended to specific locations within a table. Originally I had a script that worked just fine with changing the value of an input field rather than appending, but because I need to do some text wrapping the input field won't suffice.

Here is a snippet of the entire project (apologies, I had to edit out the specific area due to the character limit):

```js
//Course Names
var courseNames = ["Survey Design and Data Analysis", "Masters thesis Research", "Enhancing Teaching Skills", "Evaluation and Assessment", "Strategies for Dealing with the Problem Learner", "Medical Writing and Presentation Skills (Online)", "Topics in Medical Education and Medical Education Research", "Making the Most of Mentoring", "Teaching Practicum: Outpatient Teaching", "Teaching Practicum: Inpatient Teaching", "Teaching Practicum: Classroom Teaching", "Teaching Communication Skills", "Seminar Series in Medical Education", "Introduction to Systematic Reviews and Meta-Analyses"];
var list = $('#courses')[0];

courseNames.forEach(function(item) {
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.value = item;
  list.appendChild(option);
});

//Catalog Numbers
var catNumbers = ["MEDEDU 2045", "MEDEDU 2080", "MEDEDU 2100", "MEDEDU 2125", "MEDEDU 2131", "MEDEDU 2140", "MEDEDU 2160", "MEDEDU 2170", "MEDEDU 2201", "MEDEDU 2202", "MEDEDU 2203", "MEDEDU 2250", "MEDEDU 2260", "CLRES 2300", ];
var list = $('#catalogs')[0];

catNumbers.forEach(function(item) {
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.value = item;
  list.appendChild(option);
});

//Class #s
var classNum = ["30974", "13755", "13747", "27308", "22757", "13746", "13749", "17483", "13757", "13756", "13758", "13751", "16991", "27310"]

//UnitCr Array
var unitCr = ["1", "1-3", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1"]

//Days
var days = ["W", "Please", "MW", "W", "MW", "Online", "Please", "F", "Please See Instructor", "Please", "Please", "MW", "Please", "MW"]

//Times
var times = ["10:00-12:00", "See", "12:30-2:30", "3:00-5:00", "3:00-5:00", "", "See", "1:00-3:00", "", "See", "See", "1:15-4:15", "See", "9:00-11:00"]

//Building/Rooms
var bldgRm = ["305 Parkvale", "Instructor", "305 Parkvale", "305 Parkvale", "305 Parkvale", "", "Instructor", "305 Parkvale", "", "Instructor", "Instructor", "305 Parkvale", "Instructor", "222 Parkvale"]

//this is the function that is causing me trouble
function UpdateCatNumbers() {
  $('input[name=courseInput]').each(function(index) {
    $(this).change(function() {
      var a = courseNames.indexOf($(this).val())
      $('input[name=catalogInput]').eq(index).val(catNumbers[a]);
      $('.classNumID').eq(index).append(classNum[a]);
      $('.unitCreditID').eq(index).append(unitCr[a]);
      $('.daysID').eq(index).append(days[a]);
      $('.timeID').eq(index).append(times[a]);
      $('.bldgRmID').eq(index).append(bldgRm[a]);

      //$('input[name=classNumInput]').eq(index).val(classNum[a]);
      //$('input[name=unitCreditInput]').eq(index).val(unitCr[a])
      //$('input[name=daysInput]').eq(index).val(days[a]);
      //$('input[name=timeInput]').eq(index).val(times[a]);
      //$('input[name=bldgRmInput]').eq(index).val(bldgRm[a]);
    });
  });
}

//This one is too
function UpdateCourseNames() {
  $('input[name=catalogInput]').each(function(index) {
    $(this).change(function() {
      var b = catNumbers.indexOf($(this).val())
      $('input[name=courseInput]').eq(index).val(courseNames[b]);
      $('#classNumID').eq(index).append(classNum[b]);
      $('#unitCreditID').eq(index).append(unitCr[b]);
      $('#daysID').eq(index).append(days[b]);
      $('#timeID').eq(index).append(times[b]);
      $('#bldgRmID').eq(index).append(bldgRm[b]);

      //$('input[name=classNumInput]').eq(index).val(classNum[b]);
      //$('input[name=unitCreditInput]').eq(index).val(unitCr[b])
      //$('input[name=daysInput]').eq(index).val(days[b]);
      //$('input[name=timeInput]').eq(index).val(times[b]);
      //$('input[name=bldgRmInput]').eq(index).val(bldgRm[b]);
    });
  });
}

$('#lastName').focusout(function() {
  this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
});

$('#firstName').focusout(function() {
  this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
});

$('#middleInitial').focusout(function() {
  this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
});

function pdfButton() {
  if (confirm("To save your enrollment form as a PDF, change the print destination to 'Save as PDF' or change the Printer Name to 'Adobe PDF'")) {
    window.print();
    return false
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
  color: white;
  background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/f/fb/University_of_Pittsburgh_seal.svg/1200px-University_of_Pittsburgh_seal.svg.png') left center no-repeat content-box, radial-gradient(circle farthest-side, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 48%, rgba(22, 20, 66, 1) 100%) center center, linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 128, 0.35), rgba(0, 0, 128, 0.35)) center center, url('https://consideringadoption.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/pittsburgh-image.jpg') center center no-repeat, linear-gradient(rgba(22, 20, 66, 1), rgba(22, 20, 66, 1));
  background-size: 125px, 1150px;
}

.header h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
}

.header p {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000000;
}

a:link {
  color: MintCream;
}

a:visited {
  color: MintCream;
}

.body {
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(240, 206, 142, 1);
}

.sideBar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5%;
}

.bodyContent {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90%;
}

.TopInfo {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.IdInfo,
.ProgInfo,
.YearInfo {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 275px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 55px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
}

.IdInfo {
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
}

.ProgInfo {
  width: calc(30% - 10px);
}

.YearInfo {
  width: calc(20% - 10px);
}

.TopInfo:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.IdInfo input {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}

#studentID {
  width: 100%;
  letter-spacing: 15px;
}

#lastName,
#firstName {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}

#lastName {
  witdth: 50%;
}

#firstName {
  width: 40%;
}

#middleInitial {
  width: 10%
}

.ProgInfo input {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}

.YearInfo input {
  width: 100%;
  align-content: space-between;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}

.CourseInfo {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.CourseInfo p {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

.Add {
  overflow: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  width: calc(60% - 10px);
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75)
}

.Add input {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: none;
}

.Add th {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.Drop {
  overflow: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  width: calc(40% - 10px);
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75)
}

.Drop input {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.Drop th {
  font-size: 18px;
}

#dropSpace {
  margin: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .Add,
  .Drop,
  .IdInfo,
  .ProgInfo,
  .YearInfo {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

textarea {
  resize: none
}

.CourseInfo::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.body:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.footer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(22, 20, 66, 1);
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.EndPage2 {
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.studentSign {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 150px;
}

.advisorSign {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 150px;
}

.submissionButtons {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.submit {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  opacity: 0.9;
  width: 200px;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 50px;
}

.submit:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(169, 169, 169, .35);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testTemplateCss.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testTemplateCssPrint.css" media="print">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>
      ICRE Enrollment Form
    </h1>
  </div>

  <div class="body">

    <div class="sideBar">
      <h3>

      </h3>
    </div>

    <div class="bodyContent">
      <div class="TopInfo">
        <div class="IdInfo">
          <p>
            STUDENT ID
          </p>
          <input id="studentID" placeholder="##Student ID##">
          <p>
            STUDENT NAME (Last, First, M.I.)
          </p>
          <input id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" required>
          <input id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" required>
          <input id="middleInitial" placeholder="M. I." required>
        </div>

        <div class="ProgInfo">
          <p>
            PROGRAM (School)
          </p>
          <input list="program" name="progName" id="progID" placeholder="Please select your program" required>
          <datalist id="program">
     <option>ICRE</option>
     <option>Other: Please Specify</option>
    </datalist>
          <p>
            PLAN (Major)
          </p>
          <input list="plan" name="planName" id="planID" placeholder="Please select your current plan" required>
          <datalist id="plan">
     <option>Masters in Medical Education</option>
     <option>Certificate in Medical Education</option>
     <option>Masters in Clinical Research</option>
     <option>Certificate in Clinical Research</option>
    </datalist>
        </div>

        <div class="YearInfo">
          <p>
            TERM
          </p>
          <input list="term" name="termName" id="termID" placeholder="Term" required>
          <datalist id="term">
     <option>Summer</option>
     <option>Fall</option>
     <option>Spring</option>
    </datalist>
          <p>
            YEAR
          </p>
          <input list="year" id="yearID" name="yearName" placeholder="Year" required>
          <datalist id="year">
    <option>2018</option>
    <option>2019</option>
    <option>2020</option>
    <option>2021</option>
    <option>2022</option>
    <option>2023</option>
    </datalist>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Here is where I'm trying to execute the function that isn't working -->
      <div class="CourseInfo">
        <div class="Add">
          <span>
        COURSES TO BE ADDED:
 <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th style="width: 10%">Class #</th>
            <th style="width: 30%;">Course Title</th>
            <th style="width: 20%;">Catalog Number</th>
            <th style="width: 3%; font-size:16px;">Units/ Credits</th>
            <th style="width: 7%;">*Days</th>
            <th style="width: 14%;">*Time</th>
            <th style="width: 14%;">*Bldg/Rm</th>
            <th style="width: 2%; font-size:16px;">Var Credits</th>
          </tr>
   
          <tr class="trOne">
   <td class="classNumID"></td>
   <td>
   <input list="courses" name="courseInput" placeholder="Course" oninput="UpdateCatNumbers()">
      <datalist id="courses" name="courseDatalist">
     <!--Filled in script-->     
      </datalist>
   </td>
          <td>
    <input list="catalogs" name="catalogInput" placeholder="Catalog Number" id="catalogID" oninput="UpdateCourseNames()">
      <datalist id="catalogs" name="catalogDatalist">
     <!--Filled in script-->
      </datalist>
      </td>
   <td class="unitCreditID"></td>
   <td class="daysID"></td>
        <td  class="timeID"></td>
        <td class="bldgRmID"></td>
   <td><input id="varCreditID" type="text" placeholder="" ></td>
          </tr>
    
      <tr class="trOne">
   <td class="classNumID"></td>
            <td><input list="courses" name="courseInput" placeholder="Course" oninput="UpdateCatNumbers()"></td>
            <td><input list="catalogs" name="catalogInput" placeholder="Catalog Number" id="catalogID" oninput="UpdateCourseNames()"></td>
   <td class="unitCreditID"></td>
   <td class="daysID"></td>
        <td  class="timeID"></td>
        <td class="bldgRmID"></td>
   <td><input id="varCreditID" type="text" placeholder="" ></td>
          </tr>
       
  <tr class="trOne">
   <td class="classNumID"></td>
            <td><input list="courses" name="courseInput" placeholder="Course" oninput="UpdateCatNumbers()"></td>
            <td><input list="catalogs" name="catalogInput" placeholder="Catalog Number" id="catalogID" oninput="UpdateCourseNames()"></td>
   <td class="unitCreditID"></td>
   <td class="daysID"></td>
        <td  class="timeID"></td>
        <td class="bldgRmID"></td>
   <td><input id="varCreditID" type="text" placeholder="" ></td>
          </tr>
 
      <tr>
   <td class="classNumID"></td>
            <td><input list="courses" name="courseInput" placeholder="Course" oninput="UpdateCatNumbers()"></td>
            <td><input list="catalogs" name="catalogInput" placeholder="Catalog Number" id="catalogID" oninput="UpdateCourseNames()"></td>
   <td class="unitCreditID"></td>
   <td class="daysID"></td>
        <td  class="timeID"></td>
        <td class="bldgRmID"></td>
   <td><input id="varCreditID" type="text" placeholder="" ></td>
          </tr>
    
      <tr>
   <td class="classNumID"></td>
            <td><input list="courses" name="courseInput" placeholder="Course" oninput="UpdateCatNumbers()"></td>
            <td><input list="catalogs" name="catalogInput" placeholder="Catalog Number" id="catalogID" oninput="UpdateCourseNames()"></td>
   <td class="unitCreditID"></td>
   <td class="daysID"></td>
        <td  class="timeID"></td>
        <td class="bldgRmID"></td>
   <td><input id="varCreditID" type="text" placeholder="" ></td>
          </tr>
    
      <tr>
   <td class="classNumID"></td>
            <td><input list="courses" name="courseInput" placeholder="Course" oninput="UpdateCatNumbers()"></td>
            <td><input list="catalogs" name="catalogInput" placeholder="Catalog Number" id="catalogID" oninput="UpdateCourseNames()"></td>
   <td class="unitCreditID"></td>
   <td class="daysID"></td>
        <td  class="timeID"></td>
        <td class="bldgRmID"></td>
   <td><input id="varCreditID" type="text" placeholder="" ></td>
          </tr>
    
     <tr>
   <td><input list="classNum" name="classNumInput" id="classNumID" type="text" placeholder="##" readonly>
   </td>
            <td><input list="courses" name="courseInput" placeholder="Course" oninput="UpdateCatNumbers()"></td>
            <td><input list="catalogs" name="catalogInput" placeholder="Catalog Number" id="catalogID" oninput="UpdateCourseNames()"></td>
   <td><input list="unitCredit" name="unitCreditInput" id="unitCreditID"type="text" placeholder="Units" readonly></td>
   <td><input list="days" name="daysInput" id="daysID" type="text" placeholder="Days" readonly></td>
        <td><input list="time" name="timeInput" id="timeID" type="text" placeholder="Time" readonly></td>
        <td><input list="bldgRm" name = "bldgRmInput" id="bldgRmID" type="text" placeholder="Bldg" readonly></td>
      <td><input id="varCreditID" type="text" placeholder="" ></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
   <td><input list="classNum" name="classNumInput" id="classNumID" type="text" placeholder="##" readonly>
   </td>
            <td><input list="courses" name="courseInput" placeholder="Course" oninput="UpdateCatNumbers()"></td>
            <td><input list="catalogs" name="catalogInput" placeholder="Catalog Number" id="catalogID" oninput="UpdateCourseNames()"></td>
   <td><input list="unitCredit" name="unitCreditInput" id="unitCreditID"type="text" placeholder="Units" readonly></td>
   <td><input list="days" name="daysInput" id="daysID" type="text" placeholder="Days" readonly></td>
        <td><input list="time" name="timeInput" id="timeID" type="text" placeholder="Time" readonly></td>
        <td><input list="bldgRm" name = "bldgRmInput" id="bldgRmID" type="text" placeholder="Bldg" readonly></td>
      <td><input id="varCreditID" type="text" placeholder="" ></td>
          </tr>
         <tr>
  <td><input list="classNum" name="classNumInput" id="classNumID" type="text" placeholder="##" readonly>
   </td>
            <td><input list="courses" name="courseInput" placeholder="Course" oninput="UpdateCatNumbers()"></td>
            <td><input list="catalogs" name="catalogInput" placeholder="Catalog Number" id="catalogID" oninput="UpdateCourseNames()"></td>
   <td><input list="unitCredit" name="unitCreditInput" id="unitCreditID"type="text" placeholder="Units" readonly></td>
   <td><input list="days" name="daysInput" id="daysID" type="text" placeholder="Days" readonly></td>
        <td><input list="time" name="timeInput" id="timeID" type="text" placeholder="Time" readonly></td>
        <td><input list="bldgRm" name = "bldgRmInput" id="bldgRmID" type="text" placeholder="Bldg" readonly></td>
      <td><input id="varCreditID" type="text" placeholder="" ></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
   <td><input list="classNum" name="classNumInput" id="classNumID" type="text" placeholder="##" readonly>
   </td>
            <td><input list="courses" name="courseInput" placeholder="Course" oninput="UpdateCatNumbers()"></td>
            <td><input list="catalogs" name="catalogInput" placeholder="Catalog Number" id="catalogID" oninput="UpdateCourseNames()"></td>
   <td><input list="unitCredit" name="unitCreditInput" id="unitCreditID"type="text" placeholder="Units" readonly></td>
   <td><input list="days" name="daysInput" id="daysID" type="text" placeholder="Days" readonly></td>
        <td><input list="time" name="timeInput" id="timeID" type="text" placeholder="Time" readonly></td>
        <td><input list="bldgRm" name = "bldgRmInput" id="bldgRmID" type="text" placeholder="Bldg" readonly></td>
      <td><input id="varCreditID" type="text" placeholder="" ></td>
          </tr> 
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </span>
        </div>
        <div class="Drop">
          <span>
        COURSES TO BE DROPPED:
<table>
        <tbody>
  <form>
          <tr id="dropSpace">
            <th style="width: 17%;">Class #</th>
            <th style="width: 50%;">Course Title</th>
            <th style="width: 28%;">Catalog Number</th>
            <th style="width: 5%; font-size:16px;">Units/ Credits</th>
          </tr>
    </form>
          <tr>
     <td><input list="classNum" name="classNumInput" id="classNumID" type="text" placeholder="##" readonly>
   </td>
            <td><input list="courses" name="courseInput" placeholder="Course" oninput="UpdateCatNumbers()"></td>
            <td><input list="catalogs" name="catalogInput" placeholder="Catalog Number" id="catalogID" oninput="UpdateCourseNames()"></td>
   <td><input list="unitCredit" name="unitCreditInput" id="unitCreditID"type="text" placeholder="Units" readonly></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
       <td><input list="classNum" name="classNumInput" id="classNumID" type="text" placeholder="##" readonly>
   </td>
            <td><input list="courses" name="courseInput" placeholder="Course" oninput="UpdateCatNumbers()"></td>
            <td><input list="catalogs" name="catalogInput" placeholder="Catalog Number" id="catalogID" oninput="UpdateCourseNames()"></td>
   <td><input list="unitCredit" name="unitCreditInput" id="unitCreditID"type="text" placeholder="Units" readonly></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
      <td><input list="classNum" name="classNumInput" id="classNumID" type="text" placeholder="##" readonly>
   </td>
            <td><input list="courses" name="courseInput" placeholder="Course" oninput="UpdateCatNumbers()"></td>
            <td><input list="catalogs" name="catalogInput" placeholder="Catalog Number" id="catalogID" oninput="UpdateCourseNames()"></td>
   <td><input list="unitCredit" name="unitCreditInput" id="unitCreditID"type="text" placeholder="Units" readonly></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input list="classNum" name="classNumInput" id="classNumID" type="text" placeholder="##" readonly></td>
            <td><input list="courses" name="courseInput" placeholder="Course" oninput="UpdateCatNumbers()"></td>
            <td><input list="catalogs" name="catalogInput" placeholder="Catalog Number" id="catalogID" oninput="UpdateCourseNames()"></td>
   <td><input list="unitCredit" name="unitCreditInput" id="unitCreditID"type="text" placeholder="Units" readonly></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
         <td><input list="classNum" name="classNumInput" id="classNumID" type="text" placeholder="##" readonly>
   </td>
            <td><input list="courses" name="courseInput" placeholder="Course" oninput="UpdateCatNumbers()"></td>
            <td><input list="catalogs" name="catalogInput" placeholder="Catalog Number" id="catalogID" oninput="UpdateCourseNames()"></td>
   <td><input list="unitCredit" name="unitCreditInput" id="unitCreditID"type="text" placeholder="Units" readonly></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
        <td><input list="classNum" name="classNumInput" id="classNumID" type="text" placeholder="##" readonly>
   </td>
            <td><input list="courses" name="courseInput" placeholder="Course" oninput="UpdateCatNumbers()"></td>
            <td><input list="catalogs" name="catalogInput" placeholder="Catalog Number" id="catalogID" oninput="UpdateCourseNames()"></td>
   <td><input list="unitCredit" name="unitCreditInput" id="unitCreditID"type="text" placeholder="Units" readonly></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td><input list="classNum" name="classNumInput" id="classNumID" type="text" placeholder="##" readonly>
   </td>
            <td><input list="courses" name="courseInput" placeholder="Course" oninput="UpdateCatNumbers()"></td>
            <td><input list="catalogs" name="catalogInput" placeholder="Catalog Number" id="catalogID" oninput="UpdateCourseNames()"></td>
   <td><input list="unitCredit" name="unitCreditInput" id="unitCreditID"type="text" placeholder="Units" readonly></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
        <td><input list="classNum" name="classNumInput" id="classNumID" type="text" placeholder="##" readonly>
   </td>
            <td><input list="courses" name="courseInput" placeholder="Course" oninput="UpdateCatNumbers()"></td>
            <td><input list="catalogs" name="catalogInput" placeholder="Catalog Number" id="catalogID" oninput="UpdateCourseNames()"></td>
   <td><input list="unitCredit" name="unitCreditInput" id="unitCreditID"type="text" placeholder="Units" readonly></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input list="classNum" name="classNumInput" id="classNumID" type="text" placeholder="##" readonly>
   </td>
            <td><input list="courses" name="courseInput" placeholder="Course" oninput="UpdateCatNumbers()"></td>
            <td><input list="catalogs" name="catalogInput" placeholder="Catalog Number" id="catalogID" oninput="UpdateCourseNames()"></td>
   <td><input list="unitCredit" name="unitCreditInput" id="unitCreditID"type="text" placeholder="Units" readonly></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td><input list="classNum" name="classNumInput" id="classNumID" type="text" placeholder="##" readonly>
   </td>
            <td><input list="courses" name="courseInput" placeholder="Course" oninput="UpdateCatNumbers()"></td>
            <td><input list="catalogs" name="catalogInput" placeholder="Catalog Number" id="catalogID" oninput="UpdateCourseNames()"></td>
   <td><input list="unitCredit" name="unitCreditInput" id="unitCreditID"type="text" placeholder="Units" readonly></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
    </div>

    <div class="sideBar">
      <h3>

      </h3>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">

      <div class="EndPage2">
        <p>
          The student, by signing below, hereby agrees and promises to pay the University all tuition and fees resulting from this registration.
        </p>
      </div>
      <br>
      <span class="studentSign">
    Student Signature
    </span>
      <span class="advisorSign">
    Advisor Signature
    </span>

      <br>
      <br>

      <div class="submissionButtons">
        <div class="submit" onclick="pdfButton()">
          Save as a PDF
        </div>
        <div class="submit">
          Student: Submit to Advisor for Approval
        </div>
        <div class="submit">
          Advisor: Submit to SSC
        </div>
        <div class="submit">
          Advisor: Return to Student for Review
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="testTemplateJS.js"></script>

</body>
```

What seems to be happening is when I do the first row (whichever I click first) it works fine, all of the information is correctly appended to their respective cells. After that, whenever I click on a different row it correctly appends the information, but twice or three times or four depending on how many rows I've clicked.

Please help! I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Given the pattern you have, you are adding a new binding to all the existing fields each time you add a new one.  So you are making duplicate bindings.

Comment: How do I... not make duplicate bindings?

Comment: How many times are you calling `UpdateCatNumbers`?

Comment: Also does your table have a class or id on it?

Comment: The full table does not have a class or id, just the individual td's have classes. I'm calling `UpdateCatNumbers`once every time the input field is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Taplar! Since I'm new to Javascript I didn't know about event delegation. I read up on it and found a simple solution to the problem by adding "event.stopPropagation();"

Here's my updated javascript code:

```
function UpdateCatNumbers(event) {
    $('input[name=courseInput]').each(function(index) {
        $(this).change(function() {
            var a = courseNames.indexOf($(this).val())
            $('input[name=catalogInput]').eq(index).val(catNumbers[a]);
            $('.classNumID').eq(index).append(classNum[a]);
            $('.unitCreditID').eq(index).append(unitCr[a]);
            $('.daysID').eq(index).append(days[a]);
            $('.timeID').eq(index).append(times[a]);
            $('.bldgRmID').eq(index).append(bldgRm[a]);
            event.stopPropagation();
        }); 
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using event delegation.  Ref. http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Using event delegation we can create a binding on the table, that listens for events that happen on the children.  We can also use a contextual lookup for the elements in the same table row, rather than an index, to simplify the logic.

This modified method should **only be called once**.

```js
function UpdateCatNumbers() {
  //a selector for the table that the inputs are in
  //whatever that may be.  If it doesn't have a class or id
  //give it one for easy selection
  $(TABLESELECTOR).on('change', 'input[name=courseInput]', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $tableRow = $this.closest('tr');
    var a = courseNames.indexOf($this.val());

    //use the table row to find the related fields
    $tableRow.find('input[name=catalogInput]').val(catNumbers[a]);
    $tableRow.find('.classNumID').append(classNum[a]);
    $tableRow.find('.unitCreditID').append(unitCr[a]);
    $tableRow.find('.daysID').append(days[a]);
    $tableRow.find('.timeID').append(times[a]);
    $tableRow.find('.bldgRmID').append(bldgRm[a]);
  });
}
```

Comment: This works, but I need to be able to call this multiple times for each row I have.

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: This is an enrollment form for students (online rather than on paper) and the idea is they can select as many classes as they wish to enroll in. Each row has the classes our department offers.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question.  A delegate event handler will work for any row that is dynamically created in the future, if they are done so.  And a change event handler isn't a "one and done" mechanism.  When you create an event handler on the element, it stays there, and will handle any events of that type for the element until the element is destroyed, or  you remove the event handler from it.